# Widgets don't work in the Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

ipywidgets are not working in my Jupyter notebook. 
Everything else is working fine.

```
import ipywidgets as wg
from IPython.display import display 

myName = wg.Text(value='Name')
myAge = wg.IntSlider(description='Age:')
display(myName,myAge)
```

Instead of having parsed text field and slider I am getting:

```
Text(value='Name')
IntSlider(value=0, description='Age:')
```

Can you help?

Comment: How did you install ipywidgets? If installed from pip there is another command to run after installation : `jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension` Source: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause.

It simply does not work in IE ;)